# Regex to match string and all content after it to another occurrence of the same string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match every new error log line with Regex in C#.
I want to have new match every occurence of date

```
[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,ffff]
```

Here is the sample data and my current (not working) solution:

### Regex

```
(\[[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\,[0-9]{3}\])(.*)
```

### String to match

```
[2018-06-28 00:58:14,596] - INFO  - [54] - ProcessItemController - Processing url: http://somehttp.com/something.xml/
[2018-06-28 00:58:14,612] - ERROR - [54] - ProcessItemController - Processing Failed
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\SomePath\something.xlsx' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Something.Processors.PathAttachmentExtractorProcessor.XmlParser(String path, String outputPath, ProcessingItem processingItem)
   at Something.Processors.EurekaInfoPathAttachmentExtractorProcessor.ProcessItem(ProcessingItem processingItem)
   at Something.ProcessItemController.Process(Item item)
[2018-06-28 00:58:14,627] - INFO  - [69] - ProcessItemController - Processing url: http://someurl.com/cables.xml/
[2018-06-28 00:58:14,627] - ERROR - [69] - ProcessItemController - Processing Failed
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\SomePath\anotherSomething.xlsx' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Something.Processors.PathAttachmentExtractorProcessor.XmlParser(String path, String outputPath, ProcessingItem processingItem)
   at Something.Processors.PathAttachmentExtractorProcessor.ProcessItem(ProcessingItem processingItem)
   at Something.ProcessItemController.Process(Item item)
```

https://regex101.com/r/6BJpKF/1/

The problem is that when there is error log then the pattern doesn't get the exception description that is in the new line.

Is there a way to get all data between each occurence of the date (with the date itself) in separate matches?

Comment: Read a file line by line, and append to the current entry until you hit a `Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\[\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2} \d{2}(?::\d{2}){2},\d+]")` match.

Comment: If that's a stack trace you can just use a parser like this one which will save you re-inventing the wheel https://github.com/atifaziz/StackTraceParser

Comment: I don't see why you should use a single regex to do everything. Group lines until you find a datetime, then begin a new group. Discard groups of type (INFO/ERROR) you don't need.

Comment: I'm loading file to the string variable and then spliting every line ([date] - [type] - [message]) into new list item. From then I'm handling the rest of the regex stuff. The problem is that the list of each item doesn't have an error description because the initial regex I posted here doesn't match it.

Comment: @A.Kwiatkowski The lines that don't match must be grouped with their previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string input = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            string pattern = @"^(?'date'\[[^\]]+)\]\s+-\s+(?'type'[^\s]+)\s+-\s+\[(?'message'[^\[]*)";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Date : '{0}', Type : '{1}', Error Number = '{2}', Message = '[{3}'",
                   match.Groups["date"], match.Groups["type"], match.Groups["errNum"], match.Groups["message"]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That works very nice! I have one more question. How to change this pattern to have only "date", "type" and rest of info ("message"). I'm not very good at Regex :(

Comment: I modified the code to put the error number and messages in one string.  Had to make a little fudge since the open square bracket is in both the error number and beginning of the date.  I was using the open bracket as a terminator of each message which cause a little grief when I took out the error number as a separate string.  It is really cleaner to keep original code.

Answer (score 0):

Using only regex this should work:

```
string datetimeRegex = @"\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}\]";

var rx = new Regex(@"(?:^|(?<=\n))" + datetimeRegex + @"(?:(?!(?<=\n)" + datetimeRegex + @").)*", RegexOptions.Singleline);

Match m;
int ix = 0;

while ((m = rx.Match(str, ix)).Success)
{
    // Your log
    string log = m.Value;
    ix += log.Length;
}
```

But I'm not very happy. I think it is doable in a simpler way. Note that each `log` will retain its final `\r?\n`. `(?:^|(?<=\n))` means "beginning of the string or following a new line". `(?!(?<=\n)" + datetimeRegex + @")` means that a datetime preceded by a `\n` will stop the `.*` matching.